# Output last six strings

Tags: linux, apache, grep

I'm trying to parse an apache logfile.  Basically, I want to grep for 11:00 in the logfile, and then output the last six digits of every line which occurred at that time.

I'm at a loss.  Can someone help?

Comment: And your approach is ..?

Comment: I tried this:

grep "11:00" <path> > file && perl -F, -lane 'print $F[-6]' file

No luck.

Comment: And I also tried..

output=`grep "11:00" <path>` ; echo ${output: -6}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can make it:

```
awk '/11:00/ {print substr($0,length($0) - 6)}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/11:00/ {}` matches lines containing `11:00` and performs the action in `{}`.
- `print substr($0,length($0) - 6)` prints the last 6 characters of those lines: starting from "length of the string - 6" makes it, as it prints everything from that point till the end.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello bye bye
11:00 hello bye bye basd
11:23 hello this is
another line
11:00 with some text
$ awk '/11:00/ {print substr($0,length($0) - 6)}' a
ye basd
me text
```

---

## Update

Based on your comment:

> Hey, I just checked and it works! Except, my mistake .. it's the last
>   field that I need in the log, which actually varies in length, so I'm
>   guessing that I need some way of 'cutting' everything after the last
>   space! –

Let's try with the following:

```
awk '/11:00/ {print $NF}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/11:00/ {}` matches lines containing `11:00` and performs the action in `{}`.
- `print $NF` prints the last field.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello bye bye
11:00 hello bye bye basd
11:23 hello this is
another line
11:00 with some text
$ awk '/11:00/ {print $NF}' a
basd
text
```

Comment: I'm always amazed that people can do such stuff with awk.  It looks like Klingon to me!

I'll try this, thank you!

Comment: Hey, I just checked and it works!  Except, my mistake .. it's the last field that I need in the log, which actually varies in length, so I'm guessing that I need some way of 'cutting' everything after the last space!

Comment: @user2721812 then it is faster: `{print $NF}` makes it. Check my updated answer.